# Beautiful Soup extract string before tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have an xml file that has ref tags nested inside para tags:

```
<para>here be text<ref> REF 1 </ref>and here be some more text</para>
```

Is there a way using Beautiful Soup to extract the string between the opening para tag and the opening ref tag, ie:

```
here be text
```

I've tried various things to no avail, including find_previous:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')

ref = soup.find('ref')
ref_before = ref.find_previous('para')
```

But (obviously) ref_before returns the entire contents of the para tag, ie:

```
here be text REF 1 and here be some more text
```

I think this ought to be really simple but I don't have much experience and just can't crack it. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contents` and select the first element:

```
soup.find('para').contents[0]
```

Output:

```
'here be text'
```